# SSL Client Authenitcation with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I want to implement SSL client authentication with AFNetworking.

I am using a self signed certificate with my own CA. Nginx is the backend server which handles SSL client verification.

The client authentication works with curl but fails on the iOS client with AFNetworking.

Comment: How are you authenticating clients? Are you using client certificates; or are you using a shared secret scheme like TLS-PSK or TLS-SRP?

Comment: Hey thanks for the edit. Using a client cerfiticate for authentication.